# xajax and select

Tags: jquery, ajax, xajax

I have a bit of simple created with XAJAX, which replaces the innner HTML of a select control with some options created by a php script.

This is fine and dandy in Firefox, but it does not work in IE7.

Looking on the XAJAX forums i found [this](http://community.xajaxproject.org/post/27727/#p27727) which basically says " doesnt really work in IE, use a div and replace the inner HTML of that with the full select statement"

Did this, and it's fine, except that i had a jQuery selector working on the select control, which now no longer works.

Anyone got any ideas, or can anyone point me to a good jQuery example of how to do the ajax bit using jQuery, so I can ditch the XAJAX altogether?

---

#### EDIT:

```
<div id=imgselect>
  <select id="images">
   <option value="">Then select an image</option>
  </select>
</div>


Picture Preview:<br><br>

 <div class="img-preview" id='preview'></div>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
   $('#images').change(function() 
   {
     var image = $(this).val();
     var img = $('<img/>').attr('src', image);
    $('#preview').html(img);

    document.getElementById('picsmall').value = image;
    });
</script>
```

The problem comes when the contents of the `imgselect` `div` is replaced by the AJAX call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved using the

```
$objResponse->script
```

command

For the sake of completeness and if anyone wants to see in the future, I have the original page set up as above:

```
<div id=imgselect>
  <select id="images">
    <option value="">Then select an image</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

then in my xajax php file I have

```
function getphotos()
{
    $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
        //this include assigns all the options to the select controll into the $output var
    include "photos.photosselect.php";
    $objResponse->assign("imgselect", "innerHTML", "$output");
    $objResponse->script("$('#images').change(function() {var image = $(this).val(); var img = $('<img/>').attr('src', image); $('#preview').html(img); document.getElementById('picsmall').value = image;});");
    return $objResponse;
}
```